# didSelectRowAtIndexPath does nothing with no errors in debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im a newbie to xcode so im learning here, I may be going about this completely wrong but here is my scenario.  I have a storyboard of an opening view controller with a button that goes to the navigation controller this loads up my listing of entertainment from a mysql database using a table view (this is working fine) an item from the table view it show go to the details view but nothing is happening, no errors in debugger. What am i doing wrong OR have i gone about this the wrong way. I think the problem has something to do with the section in ENTERTAILMENTLISTING.M where the didSelectRowAtIndexPath stuff is going, I have included everything i have so far below.

STORYBOARD
[image]

APPDELEGATE.H

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

APPDELEGATE.M

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m


#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation AppDelegate





- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

ENTERTAINMENTLISTING.H

```
//
//  EntertainmentListingViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EntertainmentListingViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
    NSArray *events;
    NSMutableData *data;


}


@end
```

ENTERTAINMENTLISTING.M

```
//
//  EntertainmentListingViewController.m


#import "EntertainmentListingViewController.h"
#import "EntertainmentDetailsViewController.h"

@interface EntertainmentListingViewController ()

@end

@implementation EntertainmentListingViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // VIEW TITLE
    self.title = @"Entertainment";

    // SHOW NETWORK ACTIVITY INDICATOR
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    //GET DATA URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/myfile.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

//START CODE FOR TALBE VIEW

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //PROCESS JSON DATA HERE
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    events = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // WASNT ABLE TO CONNECT INTERNET THROW ERROR

    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Connection To The Internet Is Available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    // TURN OFF NETWORk ACTIVITY INDICATOR
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}


- (int) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;

}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [events count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)IndexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];



    }



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [[events objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"eImg"]];
    NSData *idata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:idata];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;


    cell.textLabel.text = [[events objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"eName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[events objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date_string"];
    return cell;
}





-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    EntertainmentDetailsViewController *entertainmentdetailsViewController = [[EntertainmentDetailsViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"EntertainmentDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    entertainmentdetailsViewController.title = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"eName"];
    entertainmentdetailsViewController.entertainmentArticle = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:entertainmentdetailsViewController animated:YES];
    // NOTHING HAPPENING HAS TO DO WITH THIS AREA I THINK
    NSLog(@"Navigation Cnntroller %@",self.navigationController);
    NSLog(@"Events COntroller %@", entertainmentdetailsViewController);

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

ENTERTAINMENTDETAILS.H

```
//
//  EntertainmentDetailsViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EntertainmentDetailsViewController : UIViewController{

    NSDictionary *entertainmentArticle;

    IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextView *descTextView;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *entertainmentArticle;

@end
```

ENTERTAINMENTDETAILS.M

```
//
//  EntertainmentDetailsViewController.m


#import "EntertainmentDetailsViewController.h"

@interface EntertainmentDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation EntertainmentDetailsViewController
@synthesize entertainmentArticle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    titleLabel.text = [entertainmentArticle objectForKey:@"eName"];
    timeLabel.text = [entertainmentArticle objectForKey:@"date_string"];
    descTextView.text = [entertainmentArticle objectForKey:@"eDetails"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere where you've set the delegate of the UITableView? In EntertainmentListing.m, set `mainTableView.delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad` method and add `<UITableViewDelegate>` to your .h declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about delegate and datasource. If you use a uitableviewcontroller, all are hooked up, if you drag a tableview to uiviewcontroller you have to do several things:

edit this line:

```
@interface EntertainmentListingViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

ctrl+drag your table to the yellow box below your view controller. set as delegate, drag again and set as source.

Comment: where is the line you say needs editing i dont see this line.  am i replacing @interface EntertainmentListingViewController () in the EntertainmentListingViewController.m ?

Comment: @ .h file, just append this string to @interface line: <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>, before the {. EntertainmentListingViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> would be ok as well @ .m file. Don't do both

Comment: done now i get this in the debugger Could not load NIB in bundle .... with name 'EntertainmentDetailsViewController''

Comment: because you use storyboards and not xib files. you need EntertainmentDetailsViewController *entertainmentdetailsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EntertainmentDetailsViewController"];, assuming that you correctly setup your storyboard ID

Comment: and if you use segues in storyboard, don't use self.navigationController pushViewController, use instead prepareforsegue. Follow some basic trainings on youtube for this.

Comment: Never assume anything with a newbie ;)  i put your line in and gave the storyboard the ID and it works.  Thank you @Calin Chitu

Comment: Good to hear that :). Keep in mind this delegate/datasource thing, there are other items that requires it as well, like uitextfield, and not only.

Comment: one more question since all my code is here...  entertainmentlistingviewcontroller tableview i am dispalying an image.  how can i display this image on the entertainmentdetailsviewcontroller?

Comment: adding these 3 lines to didselectrowatindexpath. and assigning the image to a public uiimageview property that you have to create @ your destination view.     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [[events objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"eImg"]];
    NSData *idata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:idata];

Comment: I added the 3 lines to the didselectrowatindexpath UIImage says its unused also after that im lost :) i droped a UIImageView on the details controller but dont know how to display the image in it

Comment: link the uiimageview with an outlet in .h file. entertainmentdetailsViewController.outletname.image = image;

Answer (score 0):

Assign the delegate as self and put a breakpoint to find if control reaches the delegate method

Answer (score 0):

Here EntertainmentListingViewController is a subclass of UIViewController `@interface EntertainmentListingViewController : UIViewController`. So you cant use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:entertainmentdetailsViewController animated:YES];` API. You can use `[self presentModalViewController:entertainmentdetailsViewController animated:YES];`